# Abaqus MPI parallelization supported by Windows?

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, mpi, abaqus

I am trying to run a job with MPI parallelization in Abaqus (on a private Windows PC) but the analysis doesn't start. Abaqus/CAE is not giving any error message but in the .log file the following line can be found:

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'str'**

This seems to be a python error? I modified the abaqus_v6 environment file to compile fortran by the following line:

**compile_fortran += ['/names:lowercase',]**

When the line is commented, the error message keeps occuring in the .log file though. So I think, this line should not be the problem. Has anybody an idea what could cause the error instead? Is MPI parallelization maybe not supported with windows (see link below)?

https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/2009/spring/mase5513/abaqus/docs/v6.5/books/usb/default.htm?startat=pt03ch07s19aus70.html#usb-anl-aparallelmodes

I also tried running the job with verbose=3, the error occurs after the MPI part but the last line seems to be pointing to my .com file (which I cannot influence?).

Also, when running the job with thread parallelization everything works fine.

(I am using Abaqus 2020 v6.20.1 and the MPI Library from Microsoft v10.1.12498.18 is installed. Also there should be a MPI Library with the Intel oneAPI toolkit)

Comment: MPI on Windows is a pain. Most MPI users do not run their job on Windows anymore. In fact, **no** machine of the [Top500 supercomputers](https://www.top500.org/) is running on Windows since several years. Linux is the standard system to run distributed jobs using MPI (and more generally HPC jobs).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.


In what way is it a pain? 
Sorry I am quite new to the subject and trying to understand. I am trying to compare thread-based and MPI-based parallelization or at least find valid/"scientific" arguments why MPI-based parallelization cannot be used in my case (since it seems not to work).

Comment: I personally spent a lot of time (1 week) to make a simple MPI hello-world work on Windows with someone else (it was now a decade ago, when the support was actually supposed to be better). There was many weird errors at runtime. In the end, we "fixed" the last errors by doing weird/crazy operations like disabling some network cards and running the program with admin rights... Not to mention, the documentation/support/community was pretty bad/inexistent and the tuning was difficult. The same thing on Linux (dual-boot on the same machines) worked perfectly in less than 1h.

Comment: Ui, that's a lot! 
Since I am not coding it on my own (but using Abaqus/CAE interface), do you think this also applies to my case? Normally you only have to click on "MPI" and it should work on its own - only that it doesn't (haha).